# TinyTex and Vitae failing to produce a bibliography output in template examples

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, tinytex

Each of the provided template Rmd setups from `vitae` do this.  The current output below is from the `vitae::hyndman` template.

It *looks* like it might be the UTF-8 error as the bibtex file does use french accents, and opening the .bib file in notepad++ does show it to be encoded as ANSI.   I'm not well versed with reading LaTeX logs, however.

Any advice on correcting this?  I can provde any other requested files.  As noted my (only) latex install is tinytex and I have tried reinstalling it to see if that corrects this.

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       bookdown_0.16    crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1 digest_0.6.23    dplyr_0.8.3     
 [7] R6_2.4.1         magrittr_1.5     evaluate_0.14    pillar_1.4.2     blogdown_0.17    rlang_0.4.2     
[13] rstudioapi_0.10  rmarkdown_1.18   tools_3.6.1      glue_1.3.1       purrr_0.3.3      tinytex_0.17    
[19] xfun_0.11        yaml_2.2.0       compiler_3.6.1   pkgconfig_2.0.3  htmltools_0.4.0  vitae_0.2.0     
[25] tidyselect_0.2.5 knitr_1.26       tibble_2.1.3
```

My markdown log:

```
processing file: test.Rmd
  |........                                                              |  11%
   inline R code fragments

  |................                                                      |  22%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................                                       |  44%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |.......................................                               |  56%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................                       |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-2
  |......................................................                |  78%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..............................................................        |  89%
label: unnamed-chunk-3
Writing 12 Bibtex entries ... OK
Results written to file 'curie.bib'
  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.tex --self-contained --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --template "C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\vitae\rmarkdown\templates\hyndman\resources\hyndmantemplate.tex" --number-sections --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --biblatex --lua-filter "C:/Users/Brandon/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:/Users/Brandon/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua" --wrap preserve --variable tables=yes --standalone --include-in-header "C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgjpeHg\cv-header43e01a7a18fc.tex" 
output file: test.knit.md

INFO - This is Biber 2.13
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Found 12 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'curie.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'curie.bib' to curie.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'curie.bib' for section 0
Can't decode ill-formed UTF-8 octet sequence <E9> at C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4272616e646f6e\cache-b43718b0be759cc5a59e3532d115b4e299925ade\inc\lib/File/Slurper.pm line 63.
Error: Failed to build the bibliography via biber
In addition: Warning message:
In RefManageR::as.BibEntry(.) :
  rownames of data.frame not meaningful for creating keys
Execution halted
Warning message:
Package biblatex Warning: '\DeclareSortingScheme' is deprecated.
(biblatex)                Please use '\DeclareSortingTemplate'.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 289.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '1' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '2' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '3' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '4' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '5' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '6' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '7' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '8' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '9' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '10' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '11' undefined on input line 302.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '12' undefined on input line 302.
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `test.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfile [... truncated]
```

My LaTeX log file is [here](http://dl.brandonpipher.com/files/test/test.log).

Just to be certain:

This error is produced on each of the example templates files included by the `vitae` package.  More on this can be found on the github page for `vitae` [here](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae).

I am producing this error without modifying the templates.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] including your .bib file?

Comment: Please add the rmd file directly to your question to make sure your question does not become useless to further users once your link stops working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bib file generated by RefManageR on your system does not use UTF-8 encoding, which is incompatible with what biber expects.

Before generating a bib file, set the default encoding for output files using
`options(encoding = "UTF-8")`